# Is this really widening vs autoboxing?

Tags: java, primitive, autoboxing

I saw this in [an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4384/697449), in reference to shortcomings of the Java spec:

> There are more shortcomings and this is a subtle topic. Check [this](http://kiranthakkar.blogspot.com/2007/05/method-overloading-with-new-features-of.html) out:
>
> ```
> public class methodOverloading{
>      public static void hello(Integer x){
>           System.out.println("Integer");
>      }
>
>      public static void hello(long x){
>           System.out.println("long");
>      }
>
>      public static void main(String[] args){
>          int i = 5;
>          hello(i);
>      }
> }
> ```
>
> Here "long" would be printed (haven't checked it myself), because the compiler chooses widening over auto-boxing. Be careful when using auto-boxing or don't use it at all!

*Are we sure that this is actually an example of widening instead of autoboxing, or is it something else entirely?*

On my initial scanning, I would agree with the statement that the output would be "long" on the basis of `i` being declared as a primitive and not an object.  However, if you changed

```
hello(long x)
```

to

```
hello(Long x)
```

the output would print "Integer"

What's really going on here?  I know nothing about the compilers/bytecode interpreters for java...

Comment: Certainly it's widening. Int is widened to long.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the first case, you have a widening conversion happening. This can be see when runinng the "javap" utility program (included w/ the JDK), on the compiled class:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   iconst_ 5
   1:   istore_ 1
   2:   iload_ 1
   3:   i2l
   4:   invokestatic    #6; //Method hello:(J)V
   7:   return

}
```

Clearly, you see the I2L, which is the mnemonic for the widening Integer-To-Long bytecode instruction. See reference [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Instructions2.doc6.html).

And in the other case, replacing the "long x" with the object "Long x" signature, you'll have this code in the main method:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   iconst_ 5
   1:   istore_ 1
   2:   iload_ 1
   3:   invokestatic    #6; //Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
   6:   invokestatic    #7; //Method hello:(Ljava/lang/Integer;)V
   9:   return

}
```

So you see the compiler has created the instruction Integer.valueOf(int), to box the primitive inside the wrapper.

Comment: I think it's obvious that Java has to widen before auto-boxing because older code depended on widening and would break if that code suddenly changed to auto-boxing.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is, try it out in a test.  You will see "long" printed.  It is widening because Java will choose to widen the int into a long before it chooses to autobox it to an Integer, so the hello(long) method is chosen to be called.

Edit: [the original post being referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242/why-cant-i-call-tostring-on-a-java-primitive#4384).

Further Edit: The reason the second option would print Integer is because there is no "widening" into a larger primitive as an option, so it MUST box it up, thus Integer is the only option.  Furthermore, java will only autobox to the original type, so it would give a compiler error if you leave the hello(Long) and removed hello(Integer).

Answer (score 3):

Another interesting thing with this example is the method overloading. The combination of type widening and method overloading only working because the compiler has to make a decision of which method to choose. Consider the following example:

```
public static void hello(Collection x){
   System.out.println("Collection");
}

public static void hello(List x){
   System.out.println("List");
}

public static void main(String[] args){
   Collection col = new ArrayList();
   hello(col);
}
```

It doesn't use the run-time type which is List, it uses the compile-time type which is Collection and thus prints "Collection".

I encourage your to read [Effective Java](http://books.google.com/books?id=ZZOiqZQIbRMC), which opened my eyes to some corner cases of the JLS.